# Ignoring unknown parameters: point.colour.1

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalt

I'm using ggplot2 and ggalt to construct a Dumbbell plot showing a the point at which different patients were diagnosed with a disease to the point at which they died from said disease.

I am using the following code:

```
library('ggplot2')
Library('ggalt')       
ggplot(d4, aes(x = Age.Dx, 
               xend = Current.age,
               y = Mutation,
               group = Mutation)) + 
 geom_dumbbell(color = "light blue", 
               point.colour.l = "darkred",
               point.colour.r = "darkBlue",
               point.size.l = 2.5,
               point.size.r = 2.5)
```

however I get the following warning message:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: point.colour.l, point.colour.r, point.size.l, point.size.r
```

Can anyone help, am I putting the 'point.colour.1' etc in the correct place? all I want to do is change the colour and size of the points at the end each end of the 'Dumbbells'

Thanks

`structure(list(position = c(179403522, 179403566, 179404286, 
179418418, 179418418, 179422457, 179425091, 179427963, 179433407, 
179438874, 179440067, 179441649, 179442238, 179444429, 179454576, 
179455162, 179456704, 179458085, 179469477, 179469477, 179470359, 
179477004, 179487411, 179487411, 179487411, 179632576), Var1 = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 22L, 22L, 26L, 33L, 36L, 45L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 56L, 60L, 
66L, 69L, 70L, 74L, 78L, 78L, 80L, 85L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 103L), .Label = c("179395822", 
"179400405", "179401029", "179403522", "179403566", "179404286", 
"179404491", "179406990", "179408239", "179410544", "179410799", 
"179411339", "179412245", "179412902", "179413187", "179414153", 
"179414506", "179416474", "179416530", "179416531", "179417723", 
"179418418", "179419765", "179422231", "179422249", "179422457", 
"179422725", "179423314", "179424036", "179424398", "179424496", 
"179424782", "179425091", "179426073", "179426074", "179427963", 
"179428086", "179428871", "179429468", "179429849", "179430371", 
"179430544", "179432420", "179433213", "179433407", "179433665", 
"179433758", "179434009", "179435468", "179438874", "179440067", 
"179440319", "179441015", "179441649", "179441870", "179442238", 
"179442324", "179442793", "179443339", "179444429", "179444661", 
"179452242", "179452411", "179452435", "179453427", "179454576", 
"179454957", "179455112", "179455162", "179456704", "179457005", 
"179457392", "179458075", "179458085", "179462634", "179463684", 
"179466263", "179469477", "179469738", "179470359", "179471841", 
"179472127", "179472155", "179472209", "179477004", "179477169", 
"179477885", "179478861", "179478864", "179481600", "179485012", 
"179485829", "179487411", "179497039", "179497076", "179498055", 
"179506963", "179558736", "179591957", "179604264", "179605063", 
"179605941", "179632576", "179634455", "179644174", "179658189", 
"179658211"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 34L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L), Mutation.Type = structure(c(6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "Deletion", "Deletion/Insetion", 
"Duplication", "Insertion", "Substitution"), class = "factor"), 
    Functional.Domain = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("M-band", "A-band", "I-band", 
    "Z-disk"), class = "factor"), AAA = c(179400709, 179400709, 
    179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 
    179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 
    179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 179400709, 
    179400709, 179400709, 179483311, 179483311, 179483311, 179483311
    ), BBB = c(179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 
    179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 
    179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 
    179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179483218, 179639929, 
    179639929, 179639929, 179639929), Deaceased = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Y", class = "factor"), 
    Age.Dx = c(52, 47.9, 43, 47.9, 47.9, 30, 35, 47.9, 47.9, 
    59, 37, 37, 47.9, 49, 20, 25, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9, 
    46, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9), Current.age = c(58L, 49L, 50L, 
    68L, 72L, 38L, 40L, 35L, 67L, 63L, 55L, 42L, 44L, 55L, 37L, 
    28L, 33L, 43L, 18L, 50L, 30L, 49L, 68L, 75L, 58L, 66L), Mutation = structure(c(68L, 
    NA, 23L, 52L, 52L, 96L, 18L, 83L, 49L, 3L, 46L, 56L, NA, 
    14L, 11L, 32L, NA, 13L, 44L, 44L, 70L, 69L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 100L
    ), .Label = c("p.Ala12675", "p.Ala12873fs", "p.Ala22353fs", 
    "p.Ala29119Leufs*17", "p.Ala486Serfs*26", "p.Arg14967*", 
    "p.Arg16695*", "p.Arg17736*", "p.Arg18056*", "p.Arg18858X", 
    "p.Arg18985X", "p.Arg19560X", "p.Arg19618Glufs*6", "p.Arg20858X", 
    "p.Arg21009*", "p.Arg21209*", "p.Arg22817*", "p.Arg26949X", 
    "p.Arg29415X", "p.Arg30857", "p.Arg31056*", "p.Arg31126fs", 
    "p.Arg31195X", "p.Arg31606*", "p.Arg35174Alafs*4", "p.Asn30367Lysfs*3", 
    "p.Asn30734Glnfs*17", "p.Asp14909", "p.Asp16007Profs*19", 
    "p.Asp16122", "p.Cys13771X", "p.Cys18789X", "p.Gln20809*", 
    "p.Gln24059fs", "p.Gln25689X", "p.Gln25732*", "p.Gln26147*", 
    "p.Gln27004*", "p.Gln30081X", "p.Gln4249X", "p.Glu14779fs", 
    "p.Glu15206*", "p.Glu17978fs", "p.Glu18113Aspfs*10", "p.Glu18141", 
    "p.Glu21956fs", "p.Glu23066Glyfs*8", "p.Glu23514*", "p.Glu25818*", 
    "p.Glu27300", "p.Glu29510X", "p.Glu29772*", "p.Gly10159", 
    "p.Gly16189X", "p.Gly18918Valfs*17", "p.Gly21497", "p.Gly30648Valfs*", 
    "p.Gly4007Glufs*7", "p.Gly4300Argfs*3", "p.His18335", "p.Ile20447*", 
    "p.Ile26829Metfs*15", "p.Lys14528*", "p.Lys17753Asnfs*7", 
    "p.Lys18487Serfs*3", "p.Lys21640fs", "p.Lys27131*", "p.Lys31371X", 
    "p.Phe15108fs", "p.Pro17886*", "p.Pro29241Leufs*24", "p.Ser1248Profs*14", 
    "p.Ser24241fs", "p.Ser25617Cysfs*18", "p.Ser27179fs", "p.Ser28693Ilefs*2", 
    "p.Ser28958Lysfs*10", "p.Ser29255Alafs*18", "p.Ser31841X", 
    "p.Ser493*", "p.Ser6394fs", "p.Thr21135", "p.Thr27632Serfs*5", 
    "p.Thr28262Lysfs*38", "p.Thr28262Lysfs*39", "p.Thr29725fs", 
    "p.Thr30165", "p.Thr30513fs", "p.Trp27147X", "p.Trp27591*", 
    "p.Trp29474*", "p.Trp976Arg", "p.Trp976Arg/ p.Arg19560X", 
    "p.Tyr16421*", "p.Tyr21301", "p.Tyr27567X", "p.Tyr28326fs", 
    "p.Tyr2951", "p.Tyr30384*", "p.Tyr3127*", "p.Val11879", "p.Val11879 p.Asp18235", 
    "p.Val25131Leufs*16", "p.Val26772*", "p.Val33646Hisfs*26"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("position", "Var1", "Freq", 
"Mutation.Type", "Functional.Domain", "AAA", "BBB", "Deaceased", 
"Age.Dx", "Current.age", "Mutation"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong argument names. I think their names were changed at some point.

```
library(ggalt)
ggplot(d4, aes(x = Age.Dx, 
               xend = Current.age,
               y = Mutation,
               group = Mutation)) + 
geom_dumbbell(color = "light blue", 
              colour_x = "darkred",
              colour_xend = "darkBlue",
              size_x = 2.5,
              size_xend = 2.5)
```

[image]